# twitter feed not showing when embedded in carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter, carousel

Quite an odd problem I have here. I have created an infinite carousel that keeps scrolling through 3 list items. In the first list item I have embedded a twitter widget. However this doesn't appear to be loading, instead it just says "tweets by..."

What is more bizarre is when I scroll through my carousel and it gets to the point where the twitter widget comes back around, it is now working. So it doesn't work when the page is loaded, but it does once I have gone through all the list items in the carousel once.

Can anyone suggest why thi might be happening, or even a work around for it. website is here so you can see the issue:
http://www.samskirrow.com/client-bionic

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me in Firefox on a mac, but the problem may be that in other browsers the call to twitter does not happen until the twitter carosel iframe item is rendered visible. At page load the item is not rendered, so the call may not get made at that time since it is unnecessary to load the page.

Sweet site though :)